# Matlab define callback function for mouse click on a biograph

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

all! 
This is my first question on stackoverflow!
In matlab, I create a biograph and visualize it.

```
cm = [0 1 1 0 0;1 0 0 1 1;1 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 1;1 0 1 0 0];
bg1 = biograph(cm);
view(bg1)
```

Now I want to define callback function when I click on a certain edge or node. I found from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/275948) that I can define callback function for all notes or all edges using

```
set(bg1, 'NodeCallback', 'NodeCallback_dblclick');
```

But I am wondering how to define callback function for clicking on a specific node or edge.

Anyone can help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm considering nodes in this answer. For edges it would be similar.

You need to handle the node distinction **within the callback function**. This function is **common to all nodes**, but can **know which node has been clicked** because **the node is passed as an input**. Within this function you can for example check the `ID` property of the node, and react differently depending on that.

So, first define the callback function:

```
function node_callbacks(node)
switch node.ID
case 'Node 1'
    disp('Hello, I''m node 1');
case 'Node 2'
    disp('What''s up? This is node 2');
case 'Node 3'
    disp('Hi! You''ve clicked node 3');
case 'Node 4'
    disp('I''m node 4 and I don''t want to talk!');
case 'Node 5'
    disp('Who dares bother node 5??');
end
```

and then set that as the callback function for the nodes. You should to that before viewing the graph:

```
cm = [0 1 1 0 0;1 0 0 1 1;1 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 1;1 0 1 0 0];
bg1 = biograph(cm);
set(bg1, 'NodeCallbacks', @node_callbacks)
view(bg1)
```

Comment: Please consider accepting this answer (or other answers that might show up) if it helped. For that you click the tick mark in the upper left corner at the beginning of the answer